# Getting Exception - FieldBridge for Enum Field

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am getting Exception on Enum Type field using hibernate search.

> Internal Server Error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   **org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#objectToString**    class: com.billbii.model.Empolyee   path:
>   status

my code::

```
 @Column(name = "employee_status")
    @Field(bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class),index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmpolyeeStatus status;
```

Please solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share more of the exception's stack trace?

Comment: No stack trace for this error only posted exception message received.

Comment: Somewhere there must be a stack trace. Did you check the logs?

Comment: hi Hardy , Yes i check all log. I am just receiving "Internal Server Error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#objectToString class: com.billbii.model.Empolyee path: status"

Search working fine if I removed '@Field' annotation above given column field "empolyee_status". but when i am add this '@Field'to Employee Status(its A Enum Type) for search then throws exception which i posted.

Comment: this was happening to me too, what I realized is that I was trying to search on an INT instead of STRING so I just casted to String and all was well.

Comment: Same here. I got this error. Turned out i had put the wrong field name